# Find Value per quantity based on Above row result

Tags: sql, postgresql, math

I have the following table called Temp.

S  A    B    C    D

1     10   6    0    6(Since it is first row we will assign B value)

2     25   7    10   =((25*7)+(10*6))/(25+10)=6.71

3     5    11   35   =((5*11)+(35*6.71))/(5+35)=7.24

4     10   8    30   =((10*8)+(30*7.24))/(10+30)=7.43

Can Someone tell me how we can write the logic in SQL?from the Second row you can see it is using the result of the first row.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way, but you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select s, a, b, c, b as d
      from t
      where s = 1
      union all
      select t.s, s.a, t.b, t.c,
             ( (t.a*t.b) + (t.c*cte.d) ) / (t.a + t.c)
      from cte join
           t
           on t.s = cte.s + 1
    )
select *
from cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive query is a natural approach to solve this kind of problems. However, recursion is not a strong suit of Postgres (and other RDBMS). In practice, the use of a simple iteration results in a much better performance, especially for large datasets. You need  a function to calculate the values in a loop:

```
create or replace function my_function()
returns table (s int, a int, b int, c int, d dec) 
language plpgsql as $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in
        select * from temp order by s
    loop
        s:= rec.s;
        a:= rec.a;
        b:= rec.b;
        c:= rec.c;
        d:= case when rec.s = 1 then b
            else ((a * b) + (c * d)) / (a + c) end;
        return next;
    end loop;
end $$;

select *
from my_function();

 s | a  | b  | c  |         d          
---+----+----+----+--------------------
 1 | 10 |  6 |  0 |                  6
 2 | 25 |  7 | 10 | 6.7142857142857143
 3 |  5 | 11 | 35 | 7.2500000000000000
 4 | 10 |  8 | 30 | 7.4375000000000000
(4 rows)
```